# Append value to List

Tags: immutable.js

I have a immutable list object, within a `Map` object, as follows:

```
let initialState = Immutable.fromJS({});
state = initialState;
state = state.set("myList", Immutable.List());
```

How do I append a value to "myList", thereby updating `state`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [update()](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/update) method.

```
const initialState = Immutable.fromJS({});
const state = initialState.set('myList', Immutable.List()); 

const updatedState = state.update('myList', myList => myList.push('some value'));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
emails = List(new Array<string>());
defaultValues = ['gold@gmail.com', 'saphire@gmail.com'];
this.emails = this.emails.push(...this.defaultValues);
```

This is for typescript .