# Adding single element to an immutable list

Tags: immutable.js

i want to just add an element to a list somewhere in my immutable object tree.

This question appears to have been answered here :

[Append value to List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40589928/append-value-to-list)

But for some reason it does not work for me.

If I have the following code :

```
var myState = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: [
        {name: 'hi', value: 2},
        {name: 'howdy', value: 3}
      ]
    }
  }
}
myState = Immutable.fromJS(myState);
myState = myState.update(['a', 'b', 'c'], function (myList) {
  myList.push({"name": "hallo", "value": 4})
  }
);
```

I get an error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

which indicates that the myList parameter being passed into the callback is null.

Why is this happening?

fiddle:

https://codepen.io/owatkins/pen/brMava

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update element inside List with ImmutableJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29589753/how-to-update-element-inside-list-with-immutablejs)

Comment: Check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39788499/3507464

Comment: almost, your example deals with updating something inside an element in an array. I just want to add an element to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it should be written:

```
myState.updateIn(['a', 'b', 'c'], function (myList) {
    return myList.push({"name": "hallo", "value": 4})
  }
);
```

Below is a working example:

```js
var myState = Immutable.fromJS({
  a: {
    b: {
      c: [{
          name: 'hi',
          value: 2
        },
        {
          name: 'howdy',
          value: 3
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})

myState = myState.updateIn(['a', 'b', 'c'], function(myList) {
  return myList.push({
    "name": "hallo",
    "value": 4
  })
});

console.info('myState = ' + myState.toJS())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.min.js"></script>
```

notice that I'm using `updateIn` instead of `update` and returning the result of `push`

Comment: sorry, doesn't work for me. myList is undefined in this as well.

Answer (score -1):

After much stuffing around, the only solution I could come up with is to get the array, and convert to JS, push an element onto it, then convert it back to an immutable... and then use **setIn**, NOT **updateIn**, and NOT **update**.

```
var myState = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: [
        {name: 'hi', value: 2},
        {name: 'howdy', value: 3}
      ]
    }
  }
}
myState = Immutable.fromJS(myState);

var list = myState.getIn(['a', 'b', 'c'])
var list = list.toJS();

list.push({"name": "hallo", "value": 4});

var v = Immutable.fromJS(list)

myState = myState.setIn(['a', 'b', 'c'], v)
```

This looks like a horrible solution, but it is the only thing that works for me so far.

Usually it takes about 5 minutes to learn how to add an element to a list in a framework or language.

I wasn't expecting it to take 5 ***HOURS***.

The documentation for this framework is an absolute disgrace.